# Join a sql query with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to get recent most record of a user.

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.value, t1.date
FROM table t1
JOIN (select username, max(date) as maxdate from table
      group by username) t2 on t1.username = t2.username
                           and t1.date = t2.maxdate
WHERE t1.date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Its returning a table of following structure

```
------------------------
username | value | date
------------------------
```

I have another table (t3) of following structure

```
----------------------------
username | category | group
----------------------------
```

How can I get a result similar to following table structure

```
-------------------------------------------
username | value | date | category | group
-------------------------------------------
```

How to join these relations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can JOIN it the follwing way:

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.value, t1.date, t3.category, t3.group
FROM table t1
JOIN (select username, max(date) as maxdate from table
      group by username) t2 on t1.username = t2.username
                           and t1.date = t2.maxdate
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.username=t1.username
WHERE t1.date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Hint: I do not know mysql but I think it's the same in MS SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Although a direct `join` is the most effective and fast way, if you'd do an operation such as `max(date)` on your t1 select statement (such as in your t2 select), you could construct the query in a similar way as you've done on the t2 select query:

```
SELECT maintable.username, maintable.value, maintable.date, secondtable.category, secondtable.group
FROM (
    SELECT t1.username, t1.value, t1.date
    FROM table t1
    JOIN (select username, max(date) as maxdate from table
          group by username) t2 on t1.username = t2.username
                               and t1.date = t2.maxdate
    WHERE t1.date >= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY t1.date DESC
    ) maintable
JOIN table secondtable ON maintable.username = secondtable.username
```

Note that this is in no way the best option if you're not creating a operation on the inner select.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But Somehow its performance is not up to the mark. See Andre's Answer. I have tried the both. Your query returned in 24.03 second in my server. On the contrary Andre's Query returned in 2.46 second. Though Thanks